# Smarty Templates PHP - Remove specific text from a string

Tags: php, smarty

I have the following code:

```
{$product.name}
```

This outputs all of our products, unfortunatly they are stored in the database as '`CompanyNameProductName`'.

I want to remove the string '`CompanyName`' from the string `$product.name`

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Will *CompanyName* be different for each product? If so, do you have access to it separately?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
{$product.name}
```

by

```
{$product.name|replace:'CompanyName':''|capitalize}
```

This way you can do it in your Smarty template without having to modify your PHP.

Comment: Is there any decent Smarty resources cheatsheets?

Comment: Also after removing CompanyName I need to capitalise first new letter.

Comment: Just added the capitalitze modifier. See here (http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.modifiers.php) for a list of smarty modifiers

Answer (score 3):

.

```
$str = str_replace('CompanyName','',$str);
```

https://www.php.net/str_replace

Comment: You sure live up to your gravatar. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Prestashop, you need to edit the `header.tpl` file of your theme and replace by

```
<title>{{$meta_title|replace:' - Name of your company':''}|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</title>
```

Make sure to leave the space before the dash.